# Expression engine - any exp:query inserted causes a blank page

Tags: sql, expressionengine

Whenever I insert a query like this or any other:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT c.name FROM course c"}
        {name}
{/exp:query}
```

The entire page renders blank and all it outputs is `<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>`

What am I doing wrong? If I use conventional queries, the page renders fine. The query add-on is installed according to the modules page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/)